# leaflet controols not vertically centered on mac

Tags: html, css, leaflet

i am usign leaflet, and i noticed that button controls, top right corner in my site not vertically centered. that's only on mac browsers, i tried ubuntu browsers and looks perfectly centered. how can i fix that ? i tried display flex with align-items center and it didn't work. i tried also to remove the button text inside the anchor and use instead "+" and "-" within after pseudo selectors. Always same problem.[page](https://www.feature-theming-npockui-kzowckj7hb3ey.eu.platform.sh/patternlab/?p=templates-map-search)

Can i add icon into this leaflet zoom in and out button instead of text ?

credentials: elements/avonis

html code

> ```
> <a class="leaflet-control-zoom-in" href="#" title="Zoom in" role="button" aria-label="Zoom in">+</a>
> ```

styling:

```
.leaflet-control-zoom-in, .leaflet-control-zoom-out {
  align-items: center;
  background: $primary;
  border-radius: 50%;
  color: $white;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}
```

Comment: Show some example source code here please.

Comment: @devme ok i added some piece of code

Answer (score 0):

i discovered that font-size, font-weight displayed depends on the OS. so maybe on mac browsers should be slightly different then windows browsers. so i used font-awesome font . its perfectly centered across OSs and browsers.

```
L.control.zoom({
   zoomOutText: '<i class="fa fa-minus text-white m-0 p-0"></i>',
   zoomInText: '<i  class="fa fa-plus text-white  m-0 p-0"></i>',
   position:'topright'
}).addTo(map);
```